# MVC 3 get days of month in table columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql

I am learning MVC 3, it is fun, but not always :).

I have one problem I can't solve.

I have this in my table in db

```
  id     | worker      | working_hours |    year     | month | day  |  shift

    1        worker1            5             2013      6      1        day
    2        worker2            6             2013      6      2        day
    2        worker3            7             2013      6      3        night
```

That works ok. But I would like to make it better :). But I have two problems.

1. I need table columns do be prepopulated with days of month and for each day I could see working hours
2. I need table to look something like this

> ```
>          | 1  |  2  | 3  |   Total
>
> day        5     6            11
>
> night                 7        7
> ```

That is just for 3 days in db, but I need table headers to be prepopulated with all days for month.

It seems easy, but I cant solve this one :). Can someone please give me a hand with this. I am doing all this in MVC 3 and using linq to sql connection to my db.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this if this is REALLY what you want:

```
id  |  id(from table 1)  |  Shift  | 1  |  2  | 3  | ect.....  Total

 1             1            day      5     6                    11

 2             1            night               7                7
```

Then in your primary table replace the Day column with the id from the above table and remove the Shift column. You could then add a unique key constraint to the above table so it won't allow a repeat if the id from table 1 and the shift are the same.

To be brutally honest however all this is just a bit confusing. Best bet would be to have two tables:

A:

```
id     | worker      

1        worker1 
2        worker2 
3        worker3
```

B:

```
  id     | workerid      | working_hours |    year     | month | day  |  day

    1        1                  5             2013      6      1        true
    2        1                  6             2013      6      2        true
    3        2                  7             2013      6      3        false
```

It doesn't really matter that this table will have loads of entries and doesn't read well because you then write smart queries using LINQ to pull out the data that you need to display on an MVC webpage.